# Can cwac-locpoll use multiple location providers?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

What location providers does the Android library [`cwac-locpoll`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) use to find location?
Is it restricted to GPS, or can it use other sources as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll):

> [The `Intent` for `LocationPoller`] should have another extra, keyed by `LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER`, with the name of the location provider you wish to use.

The sample code in the documentation illustrates this:

```
mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent i=new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_INTENT,
                     new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class));
i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER,
                     LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                                    PERIOD,
                                    pi);
```